# How to add angularMoment to Rails manifest file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-moment

I'm trying to use `angular-moment` (https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) in an Angular/Rails applicaton.

I've installed `angular-moment` and `angular` with bower.

Angular works and is being used in the app, but `angular-moment` crashes the app as soon as I add it as a dependency in the angular module.

**Proposed solution:**

I thought the solution might be to add `angular-moment` to the rails manifest file, `application.js`. But its also not working.

**Application.js**

```
//= require angular
//= require angularMoment
```

**Bower.json**

```
"dependencies": {
  "angular": "^1.5.5",
  "angular-moment": "^0.10.3"
}
```

**App.js**

```
angular.module('App', ['angularMoment'])
```

Is there a known reason why this might not work?

Or some alternative you would recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Use `//= require angular-moment` in the manifest file, not `//= require angularMoment`.

Note to self - required file in `application.js` should match the file name in `bower.json`, not the name used in the Angular injection.